# Make WPF TextBox Margins Clickable/Selectable

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a WPF `TextBox` with a white background. I've given it some `Padding` so that the text has a "margin" around it (akin to the margins in, say, MS Word).

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Padding="25" />
```

Unlike in Word, however, this blank area around the text is not "active" (see color-coded illustration below). Clicking within it (the red section) doesn't move the textbox's caret, nor will it begin a selection. Note, however, that the *entire* green area *is* active - even the blank space below the text (meaning you can click within it to move the caret or start a selection)...

[image: textbox with colored alive/dead zones]

So, my question is this: Is there any way to add space around a`TextBox` that is blank but is also part of the editable area (so that it will react to clicks/selections, like the blank area of the green section does)?

Thanks!

p.s. The closest I've come in my search for an answer was this: [How to set the margin on a internal TextBoxView in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979523/how-to-set-the-margin-on-a-internal-textboxview-in-wpf/28650200#28650200)... However, while increasing the `Margin` of the inner `TextBoxView` does increase the space around the text, that space still doesn't seem to be "active" in any way... And it seems like the `TextBoxView` doesn't have a `Padding` property, so I can't try that (though I imagine `Padding` is more likely to be the solution than a `Margin`)...

Comment: Upvoted this. I'm trying to figure out the exact same thing!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused why it's not a popular question. The TextBox has a counterintuitive Padding behavior for sure.

Looked at Microsoft referencesourece for TextBox selection code but it turns out too complicated to inject a fix. So Behavior attached property seems to be a simplest way to achieve this.

xaml:

```
<TextBox Padding="24 0" local:TextBoxSelectionBehavior.IsEnabled="True"/>
```

c#:

```
public static class TextBoxSelectionBehavior
{
    public const double MAX_DISTANCE = 10;
    private static TextBox control;
    private static Point pos;
    private static int start;
    private static int cur;
    private static double right;
    private static bool drag;
    private const double MAXDRAG = 12;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxSelectionBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsEnabledChanged));
    public static bool GetIsEnabled(FrameworkElement obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    public static void SetIsEnabled(FrameworkElement obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    private static void IsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = (TextBox)d;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            v.PreviewMouseDown += V_PreviewMouseDown;
            v.PreviewMouseUp += V_PreviewMouseUp;
            v.PreviewMouseMove += V_PreviewMouseMove;
            v.LostFocus += V_LostFocus;
            v.IsKeyboardFocusedChanged += V_IsKeyboardFocusedChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            v.PreviewMouseDown -= V_PreviewMouseDown;
            v.PreviewMouseUp -= V_PreviewMouseUp;
            v.PreviewMouseMove -= V_PreviewMouseMove;
            v.LostFocus -= V_LostFocus;
            v.IsKeyboardFocusedChanged -= V_IsKeyboardFocusedChanged;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickSelectsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ClickSelects", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxSelectionBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
    public static bool GetClickSelects(FrameworkElement obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(ClickSelectsProperty);
    public static void SetClickSelects(FrameworkElement obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(ClickSelectsProperty, value);

    private static void V_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton != MouseButton.Left) return;
        if (control != null) { control.ReleaseMouseCapture(); control = null; }
        if (e.OriginalSource is Grid g && (System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(g) as FrameworkElement)?.Name == "PART_ContentHost")
        {
            control = (TextBox)sender;
            pos = e.GetPosition(control);
            var r = control.FindChild<ScrollContentPresenter>().Content as FrameworkElement;
            right = r.TranslatePoint(new Point(r.ActualWidth, 0), control).X;
            cur = start = control.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(pos, true) + (pos.X >= right ? 1 : 0);
            control.SelectionStart = start;
            control.SelectionLength = 0;
            control.Focus();
            control.CaptureMouse();
            drag = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private static void V_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (control == null) return;
        var p = e.GetPosition(control);
        cur = control.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(p, true);
        control.SelectionStart = Math.Min(start, cur);
        control.SelectionLength = Math.Abs(cur - start) + (p.X >= right ? pos.X >= right ? -1 : 1 : 0);
        if (!drag) drag = Math.Max(Math.Abs(pos.X - p.X), Math.Abs(pos.Y - p.Y)) > MAXDRAG;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    private static void V_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (control == null) return;
        control.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        if (!drag && GetClickSelects(control)) control.SelectAll();
        e.Handled = true;
        control = null;
    }
    private static void V_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (control != null && control != sender) return;
        if (control != null) control.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        control = null;
    }
    private static void V_IsKeyboardFocusedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (control != null && control != sender) return;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue) return;
        if (control != null) control.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        control = null;
    }
}
```

And this attached property could be easily assigned globally by a general Style setter for a TextBoxes.