# TextBlock vs TextBox Padding - XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add padding to a textblock and a textbox on the same horizontal alignment (so the text for both starts at the same horizontal location), but it seems to me that the padding for a textblock vs a textbox is off?

I have this code:

```
<TextBox Text="Test"
             BorderThickness="0"
             Margin="0"
             Padding="12,0,0,0" />
<TextBlock Text="Test"
           Margin="0"
           Padding="12,0,0,0" />
```

But on my display, is shows up as this (Stackpanel): [image: stackpanel]

Grid: [image: grid]

Esentially, my question is, the padding is the same, so what's up with the horizontal alignment?

Comment: You may have more luck with a Label instead of TextBlock, as the latter doesn't really have content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding represents the distance between the side of the control (which can be the margin) and its content.

Well using your Xaml, I used the Snoop utilty and found out that the Textbox has more inner control. For example border,TextBoxView etc... Refer the below image.
[image]

But, in case of  TextBlock, there were none. 
One of the control in Textbox control is TextBoxView, checking out the margin it has 2,0,2,0.

[image]

I changed the Margin = -1,0,0,0 and the content padded properly. So the content was padding against the textBoxView. and making the Margin of the textBoxView  equal to -1,0,0,0. it appeared correct with TextBlock alignment.

[image]

Comment: You cannot modify the margin of the internal `TextBoxView` of `TextBox` in XAML *easily*. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19979563/11942268) suggests to modify the margin of `TextBox` instead: `Margin="-2 0 -2 0"`. That worked at least in my case.